# Plane to always face object

Tags: rotation, quaternion

How do i get a plane to always face an object with the flat/mesh/xy side? I tried sticking in Vector3. forward and up but i always get the plane facing the object on an edge.

```
    void Update()
{
    planeRotate.transform.LookAt(cube.transform, );
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The face of a plane primitive points in its local "up" direction (y+), not the local "forward" direction (z+) used by `LookAt`.

So you want a rotation that takes the y+ axis to point toward the target:

```
Vector3 directionToTarget = cube.transform.position - planeRotation.transform.position;
planeRotation.transform.rotation = Quaternion.FromToRotation(Vector3.up, directionToTarget);
```

If you have a preferred "twist" direction you want the z+ axis to face, you gan enforce that like so:

```
Vector3 zTarget = Vector3.up;

Quaternion zToTarget = Quaternion.LookRotation(directionToTarget, -zTarget);
Quaternion yToZ = Quaternion.Euler(90, 0, 0);

planeRotation.transform.rotation = zToTarget * yToZ;
```

Comment: how do i stop it from tumbling around, stop it from rotating around y+ while it rotates to face the cube?